# Asymptotically efficient estimators from stationary points of the likelihood function

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

Is there an example of a parameterized model (i.i.d.) in which the maximum likelihood estimate is consistent (e.g., in probability) but not asymptotically efficient, but there exists a sequence of stationary points of the likelihood function that is asymptotically efficient?   Alternatively, does anyone know of a theorem that precludes this possibility?  For example, Theorem 5.1 of Lehmann & Casella, 2nd ed., p. 463 does not rule out such a possibility even when the usual regularity conditions are satisfied.  In particular, that theorem does not say anything about the maximum likelihood estimate itself, only stationary  points of the likelihood function.  This would seem to be a rather fundamental question in classical statistics, and if such behavior were not possible, existing standard theorems (such as Theorem 5.1 above) would say something stronger than they do.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi: MLEs are known to be asymptotically efficient ( attain Cramer Rao Lower Bound ) but there are regularity conditions ( regarding the theorem for asymptotic efficiency ) that need to be met. for the CR lower bound. I don't remember what they are but that's where you might find an exception.

Comment: Hi: I'm stumped but maybe check out the uniform distribution $(0,\theta)$ because the MLE of $\theta$, in that case, ( which is max of sample observations ), I don't think satisfies the usual regularity conditions. So, maybe see if the behavior of $max(x_{1},x_{2}, \ldots, x_{n})$ , has the behavior you are looking for.